# code to subscribe a user to a list in mailchimp

Tags: c#, mailchimp

When I execute the below code, the mail id is not added to the list, but the "result" parameter contains the value of Email,EUIdl, LEId. Anyone can give the exact code. The code taken from
https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET

```
MailChimpManager mc = new MailChimpManager("5323a23b12022d250c23c48253641dd5-us8");

//  Create the email parameter
EmailParameter email = new EmailParameter()
{
    Email = "riyas.k13@gmail.com"
};

EmailParameter results = mc.Subscribe("33cacee7d8", email);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [MCAPI](http://mcapinet.codeplex.com/documentation) this is the call to subscribe to a list, you might want to check all the options in the subscribeOptions, and determine your required Merge values

```
MCApi mc = new MCApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MCAPIKey"], false);

var subscribeOptions = new Opt<List.SubscribeOptions>(new List.SubscribeOptions { SendWelcome = true, UpdateExisting = true });
var merges = new Opt<List.Merges>(new List.Merges { { "FNAME", [Subscriber FirstName here] }, { "LNAME", [Subscriber lastName here] } });

if (mc.ListSubscribe(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MCListId"], [Subscriber email ], merges, subscribeOptions))
    // The user is subscribed Do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the code seemed to work but no email was added to the list. The code does work by the way.

When a new email address is added to the mail list MailChimp sends out a confirmation email to that address, which you need need to confirm naturally.

If you don't do this the new email address won't be added to the list. If you didn't receive any email at the target address check the spam folder or see if any filters have accidentally caught it without you realising.

Sad to say I spent a good few hours going around in circles because of this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on maichimp list setting when you created the list. There is something called "ask users to confirm the subscription". By default, if admin checked this option, after importing, the users will receive confirmation emails. New added user names will be added only if they confirmed.

If you don't want to sent confirmation emails but directly added new users. **Set "DoubleOptIn" to false.**

```
/*
Set subscribe options
*/
MailChimp.Types.List.SubscribeOptions option = new MailChimp.Types.List.SubscribeOptions();
option.UpdateExisting = true;
option.DoubleOptIn = false;

List<MailChimp.Types.List.Merges> lstMerges = new List<MailChimp.Types.List.Merges>();
/*
Merge new users here.
*/

returnStatus = api.ListBatchSubscribe("your MailChimp List ID", lstMerges, option);
```